# Junit: testing thrown exception while using exception mapper

Tags: exception, java-ee-7, exceptionmapper

How can I use Junit4 to test the thrown exception while using the exception mapper ?

Comment: any updates here? also which exception is expected to be thrown by your test should be stated to make question more informative

Answer (score 0):

To test a thrown exception, expected from the execution. Please use :

```
@Test(expected=<ExpectedException>.class)
public void testThrownException() {
// Your test code that throws the expected exception
}
```

The test would pass if your code throws the expected exception and fail for assertion failures and any other exception thrown by the code.